# Shrinking log file in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to shrink log file in SQL Server to save storage space but instead of decreasing the file size has been increased with a large volume.
I have tried this twice, both of the time file size was increased.

Comment: So what did you do exactly?

Comment: What is the default size of your file ? If the target size is not specified, the file size is reduced to its *default* size. Have a look at [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-shrinkfile-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: What's the database's recovery model? `SELECT name, recovery_model_desc FROM sys.databases WHERE db_id = db_id() ;`

Answer (score 2):

From what you have provided, it seems as if you ran `DBCC SHRINKFILE` on the log file, and it did not shrink. This is likely due to there not being any free space to actually shrink. What you want to do instead is [`BACKUP` the log file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/back-up-a-transaction-log-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017), which will free up space, and allow you to shrink the log file back to your specified size. Afterwards, you probably want to schedule these backups based on [your RPO and RTO](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/the-accidental-dba-day-6-of-30-backups-understanding-rto-and-rpo/), which it sounds like you don't have so I'd figure out what that is first.

Since it *seems* like your log file is growing pretty consistently, I'd assume you are in [`FULL or BULK LOGGED RECOVERY` mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/recovery-models-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017). Regardless, you'll have to conduct a [`FULL BACKUP`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/full-database-backups-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) before you can do a `LOG BACKUP`.

If this happens to be `TEMPDB`, [clearing the cache can help](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/02/when-shrinking-tempdb-just-wont-shrink/).